# Windows Server 2019 Event Forwarding returns 0 Source Computers

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

So I've configured my Windows Server 2019 as an event logger to get the events of shutdown,and logoff from my domain computers. I've included the DOMAIN\Domain Computers group and configured the Event Forwarding Subscription Group Policy through http as explained [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/windows-event-forwarding-to-a-sql-database/) with my SQDN as listed in the system properties. I've also allowed the 5985 port through my firewall just in case, and after all this configurations I still get 0 source computer. If you need see any concret configuration I will edit my question. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following command on the collector: `wecutil gs <YourSubscriptionName>`

Comment: @Swisstone sorry, I finally found my issue and corrected it myself, and forgot to write a response.

Comment: Remember to mark the problem as solved by clicking the outline of the tick mark so that it turns solid green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what my mistake was. I had to start `winrm` service on every source computer, as well as configuring the Event Forwarding Suscription Group Policy. To do this I followed [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wec/setting-up-a-source-initiated-subscription) Microsoft official guide. (the *Configuring the event source computer* section)